# Setting layout of first ListView Item

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So I am attempting to set a different layout resource for my first ListItem element using this code:

```
int type;
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    if(position==0) {
        type = R.layout.queue_item_next;
    } else {
        type = R.layout.queue_item;
    }

    return type;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(getItemViewType(position), parent, false);
    }
```

This code works however with some unexpected behavior. For some reason the last element of the ListView is also being set to have this alternate layout and I have no idea why.

What could cause this to happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe because `convertView ` is being reused. Remove `if` condition and check if it works?

Comment: I'm not hundred percent sure, but I think it's related to view recycling. You currently check if convertView is null, but I think you must also check the current type of the convertView. You could store that in the tag of convertView to perform this check

Comment: but not adding check for convertView will increase memory when number Items to be displayed is large, violating concept of recycling view.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is coming due getItemViewType() is returning value greater than number of view types. You can use bellow code working perfectly fine for me.

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        if(position==0) {
            return 0;
        } 
        return 1;
    }

   @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if(type == 0)
            convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, parent, false);
        else 
        convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_layout, parent, false);
        }
}
```

Note : If only first view is different then best option is to use headerView using function listview.addHeaderView() function using this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean))

Answer (score 0):

because you are using `if(convertView == null) {}`
that means if previous view is available in memory use that one else create a new one. So, sometimes on scroll fast/slow depends on resources available of phone it varies.

to solve this problem dont check `if(convertView == null)`

use like this

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(getItemViewType(position), parent, false);
    }
```